# servos act strangely instead of stopping/starting

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, code-review

I am trying to make it so that my robot rolls straight when pin 8 is high and stop when pin 8 is low, the 2 servos is constant rotation servos. instead the servos spin when the wire touches it pin even without power to the wire, and they don't stop when the wire is pulled, but sometimes they don't start and sometimes they stop.
I'm new to coding and I really need this help.

```
#include <Servo.h>


Servo h1;
Servo h2;


#define servoPin 13
#define servoPin 3

int angle = 0;
const int buttonPin = 8;
int buttonState = 0;
void setup() {

  h2.attach(13); //left servo
  h1.attach(3); //right servo
  pinMode(8, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
 
  if (digitalRead(8) == LOW)  {
  h1.write(90); //no movement
  h2.write(90);//no movement
  
  } else  {
    h1.write(180); //go straight
    h2.write(0); //go straight
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you change `INPUT` to `INPUT_PULLUP`?

Comment: reduce your code to repeatedly print the state of pin 8 ... what do you observe?

Comment: As VE7JRO suggested, this really sounds like a floating pin. I guess you have a button on that pin, which connects the pin to ground when pressed, but you don't have an external pullup resistor. Using `pinMode(pin, INPUT_PULLUP)` will activate the internal pullup resistor for that pin.

Comment: Are you aware that there are at least two very different types of servos? Are you sure that the library you use matches the type of servo you attached?